# Looking for ideas to improve Weighted Moving Average result

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have two data sets:

```
Dataset#1:

Frequency | Score
------------------
   1      | 100

Dataset#2:

Frequency | Score
------------------
   50     | 80
   60     | 90
```

The Weighted average of the Dataset #1 is 100
The Weighted average of the Dataset #2 is 85.45

The dataset#2 is much more credible and reliable since it has more data,

What techniques can I use such that it discredit outliers low frequency datasets like Dataset#1 above and boost highly populated high score datasets like Dataset#2?